# How to add labels to specific points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add labels to specific countries in my plot rather than just labelling every single country. is there a way to do this? my deadline is tomorrow.

for example I would like to label just Chile, Mexico, Germany, Singapore and Nigeria - how can this be done?

[image]

below is my code:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot2")
library("readstata13")

setwd("/Users/eesahamin/Downloads")

Base_df <- read_csv(file = "JHU-UN-IPU_Covid.csv")
Base_df <- unique(Base_df)

df1 <- select(Base_df, country, monthlyDateN, continent_name, population, people_partially_vaccinated, people_fully_vaccinated, doses_admin)
df2 <- filter(df1, continent_name!="Oceania", monthlyDateN == 2021.09, country!="Albania", country!="Argentina", country!="Bangladesh", country!="Benin", country!="Brazil", country!="Burkina Faso", country!="Burundi", country!="Cabo Verde", country!="Central Africa Republic", country!="Chad", country!="China", country!="Colombia", country!="Comoros", country!="Congo (Brazzaville)", country!="Cuba", country!="Djibouti", country!="Eritrea", country!="Estonia", country!="Guniea-Bissau", country!="Haiti", country!="India", country!="Indonesia", country!="Italy", country!="Khazakhstan", country!="Lebanon", country!="Lesotho", country!="Lithuania", country!="Madagascar", country!="Malaysia", country!="Nepal", country!="Niger", country!="Poland", country!="Slovenia", country!="Somalia", country!="Switzerland", country!="Tajikistan", country!="Timor-Leste", country!="Ukraine", country!="Yemen", country!="Central African Republic", country!="Guinea-Bissau", country!="Kazakhstan")

df3$originallabel <- c("Chile", "Mexico,", "Germany", "Russia", "Pakistan", "Singapore", "Nigeria")

plot1 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = people_fully_vaccinated/population*100, y = continent_name))
plot1 + geom_point(aes(size = population, color = continent_name), alpha = 2/5)

plot2 <- plot1 + geom_boxplot(aes(outlier.color = NULL)) + geom_jitter(aes(size = population, 
color = continent_name), alpha = 2/5, height  = 0.2) + element_text(df3, aes(label=label))

final <- plot2 + labs(x = "Percentage of Population Fully / Double Vaccinated", y = "Continent", 
title = "Propotion of Population with Full / Double COVID-19 Vaccinations by Sep. 2021", 
size = "Population", caption = "Sources: John Hopkins University COVID-19 Vaccination Data, 
John Hopkins University Centers for Civic Impact.")

final <- final + theme_grey() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 13.5, face = "bold"),
axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "italic"), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12,
face = "italic"), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
legend.title = element_text(size = 12))

# Removing "Colour" legend as it is not necessary to show

final + guides(color=FALSE)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you'd like to add a few specific custom text/labels to the plot, you can use `annotate()` (click [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html) for details). It allows you to plot something (e.g., the labels) on specific x,y-coordinates. It's great if you just have a few labels to insert (tedious if you have too many). Side comment,  "Proportion" in your title is misspelled.